# Using VB.NET IIF I get NullReferenceException

Tags: .net, vb.net, nullreferenceexception

I am doing a little debugging, and so I want to log the eventArgs value

I have a simple line that basically does:

```
logLine = "e.Value: " + IIf(e.Value Is Nothing, "", e.Value.ToString())
```

The way I understand the IIF function, if the e.Value is Nothing (null) then it should return the empty string, if not it should return the .ToString of the value. I am, however getting a NullReferenceException. This doesn't make sense to me.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

[IIf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d.aspx) is an actual function, so all arguments get evaluated.  The [If](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) keyword was added to VB.NET 2008 to provide the short-circuit functionality you're expecting.

Try

```
logLine = "e.Value: " + If(e.Value Is Nothing, "", e.Value.ToString())
```

Comment: Also: If() is typesafe.  IIf() is not.

Comment: I still have problem using the short circuit If with types like Date and Boolean and yet still assigning to a nullable type. For example I want to return 'Nothing' just like above to a Nullable Boolean value using 'If' but it still returns 'False'. Crazy thing when I break the lines out to a If-Else-End If the logic works as expected.

Comment: @atconway, apparently `Nothing` in VB is like `default` in C#, rather than `null`, so when used in a context where `Boolean` is the implied type, its value is `False` instead of `null`/`Nothing` as you'd typically think of it (per http://stackoverflow.com/q/1828173/2688).  You'll need to cast one side of the `If` to the correct type (e.g. `Boolean?`) to get the desired result.  Similarly in C#, you need to cast one side (but it's a compile error if you don't).

Answer (score 4):

VB does not do short-circuiting evaluation in Iif.  In your case, e.Value.ToString() is being evaluated no matter whether e.Value is nothing.

Comment: Do you know a solution then ?

Comment: Yes, use `If` as the selected answer suggests.

Answer (score 3):

This is the expected behaviour.

`IIF` is a function; therefore the parameters for the function will be evaluated before sending it to the function.

In contrast, the ternary operator in C# is a language construct that prevents the evaluation of the second parameter if the expression of the ternary is true.