# Nullable(Of ) is not set to Nothing in conditional ternary operator

Tags: vb.net, double, nullable

Why I can't set Nothing to Nullable(Of Double) through conditional ternary operator but I can directly?

```
Dim d As Double? = Nothing
d = If(True, 0, Nothing)    ' result: d = 0
d = Nothing                 ' result: d = Nothing
d = If(False, 0, Nothing)   ' result: d = 0 Why?
```

Edit: These work (based on below accepted answer):

```
d = If(False, 0, New Integer?)
d = If(False, CType(0, Double?), Nothing)
d = If(False, 0, CType(Nothing, Double?))
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1828205/1070452

Comment: `Option Strict On` will give you feedback much faster in this kind of situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Nothing` converts to a lot of types, not just `T?`. It can happily convert to `Double`:

```
Function X() As Double
    Return Nothing ' result: 0.0
End Function
```

or to `Integer`. It's that sense of `Nothing` that you're using in `If(X, 0, Nothing)`, because `If` needs the second and third arguments to match in type: it treats it as type `Integer`, because that's the type of `0`.

Explicitly specifying one of the types as nullable (either `Integer?` or `Double?` would work) lets the compiler figure out what you want:

`d = If(False, CType(0, Double?), Nothing)`, or `d = If(False, 0, CType(Nothing, Double?))`

Comment: I can't edit my comments yet and I didn't expect that hitting 'enter' will post my comment. Anyway I marked your answer. Also @Plutonix pointed me out right path. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: `Nothing` not converts it is simply the default value of the type. For `int` it is `0`, for reference types it is `null`

Comment: @Fabio The language specification describes it as a conversion, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711655(v=vs.71).aspx.

Comment: @hvd, sorry but your link reference to the obsolete description - check latest one: [Nothing (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x9tb07z(v=vs.140).aspx)

Comment: @Fabio That's the language reference, not the language specification. The current language specification is linked at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms234437.aspx and contains the same wording as the old language specification, it's just not possible to link to a chapter in there.

Comment: @hvd .- thanks you made me download and read/learn new staff about Visual Basic :). So if I understand right by specification `Nothing` is literal which convertible to default value of all types. And by implementation(current compiler) it is keyword representing default value of given type.

Comment: @Fabio By specification, yes. By implementation, I'm not sure. I don't know precisely what the compiler does to make `If(True, Nothing, 1)` return `0`. When the compiler first sees `Nothing`, it hasn't seen `1` yet, so it cannot know yet that it's going to represent the default value of `Integer`. Yet it must keep track of the `Nothing` somehow. I suspect that it's implemented as a conversion in the compiler itself too, but I don't know for sure.