# Using IIf in an expression

Tags: vb.net

Assuming `totallvl` is an integer and `chclass1` has been created but `chclass2` has not, why can I do this:

```
totallvl = chclass1.level
If chclass2 IsNot Nothing Then
    totallvl = totallvl + chclass2.level
End If
```

but not this?

```
totallvl = chclass1.level + IIf(chclass2 Is Nothing, 0, chclass2.level)
```

It's like the compiler is assuming I'll use `chclass2` in this example but not in the first example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [vb.net: how is iif giving a null reference exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454167/vb-net-how-is-iif-giving-a-null-reference-exception)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IIf` is just a function; `chclass2.level` is evaluated regardless of what the first argument is. If you want an inline conditional operator similar to other languages, use an actual inline `If` (available in VB 2008 and later):

```
If(chclass2 Is Nothing, 0, chclass2.level)
```

Answer (score 2):

its because all function arguments are resolved when the function is called.  The if statement only runs code in the "true" part of the statement block.