# vb.net - IIf throwing strange exception

Tags: vb.net, ternary-operator, iif

I am having a weird problem. IIf is messing up when I am working with an array. Apparently it is checking my else statement even though it isn't activated. Here is some code that demonstrates the issue:

```
'works
 Dim test As String = "bleh"
 If values.Length < 6 Then
   test = "200"
 Else
   test = values(5)
 End If

 'throws indexoutofrange exception
 Dim itemLimit As String = IIf(values.Length < 6, "200", values(5))
```

Comment: What version of VisualStudio are you using?

Comment: I am using Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using VB.NET IIF I get NullReferenceException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428959/using-vb-net-iif-i-get-nullreferenceexception)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Iif` operator doesn't implement short circuiting and will evaluate both the true and false case.  If you want a short-circuit version then use `If`.

```
Dim itemLimit As String = If(values.Length < 6, "200", values(5))
```

Comment: Thanks! You provided the problem & a solution. My only question is what is the point of IIF if it evaluates both the true and false case?

Comment: @Phil `IIf` has been around since at least VB 7 (original release of VB.Net).  At that time VB didn't implement short circuiting for the majority of their constructs (`And` / `Or` don't actually short circuit).  This function was designed at that time and hence didn't add short circuiting logic

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this article: http://www.fmsinc.com/free/newtips/net/nettip33.asp

From the article:

> Visual Basic, VBA, and Visual Basic
>   .NET support the IIF function as an
>   alternative to the If...Then...Else
>   statement. Although this may seem like
>   a shortcut, IIF functions differently
>   than If...Then...Else.
>
> IIF must evaluate the entire statement
>   when preparing the argument, which can
>   lead to undesirable side effects.

In other words, your `If...Then...Else` works because the `Else` clause isn't being evaluated if the condition fails.  The `IIf`, on the other hand, evaluates all the statements, causing the `IndexOutOfBounds` exception.