# how-to-handle-nullreferenceexception

Tags: vb.net, nullreferenceexception

I would like to ask how I can contain the error I am getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",nullreferenceException .I am trying to assign the value I am getting from the gridview to a variable. I get the error on the first line. how can I handle a situation when the value is null.I've tried using isnot Nothing but its still giving me the error and isdbnull wont work because I am not dealing with a datatable .

I only get this error when the gridview is still empty how can I handle this.

```
If Not IsNothing(ProductsRawMaterialGrid.GridViewElement.CurrentRow.Cells("PercentageInMix").Value) Then
    PIM = ProductsRawMaterialGrid.GridViewElement.CurrentRow.Cells("PercentageInMix").Value
Else
    PIM = FormatNumber("0.00", 2)
End If
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using VB.NET IIF I get NullReferenceException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428959/using-vb-net-iif-i-get-nullreferenceexception)

Comment: Not a exact duplicate, but the accepted answer on the other question will work perfectly for this question.

Comment: Perhaps your problem start with CurrentRow when the grid is empty. That's the object reference that fails.

Comment: @Stefan: No, it won't.  The other question is about an operator not short-circuiting; the problem in this question is that there's not enough null checking.

Comment: @DanPuzey, true, the 'question' itself is not a duplicate, but the answer on that question would solve this questions problem.

Comment: How does that answer help?  You'd need 5 `If` statements to protect the full expression ProductsRawMaterialGrid.GridViewElement.CurrentRow.Cells("PercentageInMix").Value` from null refs.  The answer you linked explains how to use `If` as a short-circuited version of `Iif`, which is a different problem - there's no issue with (lack of) short-circuiting here.

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't know what is `null` in your line of code.  Considering the problem line, you have this expression:

```
ProductsRawMaterialGrid.GridViewElement.CurrentRow.Cells("PercentageInMix").Value
```

There are six things that could evaluate `null` in that expression:

- `ProductsRawMaterialGrid` could be `null`
- `ProductsRawMaterialGrid.GridViewElement` could be `null`
- `ProductsRawMaterialGrid.GridViewElement.CurrentRow` could be `null`
- `ProductsRawMaterialGrid.GridViewElement.CurrentRow.Cells` could be `null`
- `ProductsRawMaterialGrid.GridViewElement.CurrentRow.Cells("PercentageInMix")` could be `null`
- `ProductsRawMaterialGrid.GridViewElement.CurrentRow.Cells("PercentageInMix").Value` could be `null`

You are only checking one of them (the last one).  Unfortunately if any of the others are `null`, you will see a `NullReferenceException`.

An educated guess would be that either `CurrentRow` is `null` when you call the code, or that your cell name is wrong and `.Cells("PercentageInMix")` is `null`.  Splitting this code out or examining it in the debugger should help you resolve the issue.

Comment: Indeed, but the OP used `null` so I'm assuming they worked that out :-)  Always thought it was silly using `Nothing` in VB because it makes `NullReferenceException` a little meaningless!