# Lambda check for null on Array of objects - ArgumentNullException

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get a string of `BranchCode` from an array of `UserBranches()`. For a specific user the list is nothing, therefore is causing an exception:

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: source'

I am using an `IIF` statement, but obviously does not help:

```
Dim sMatchedBranches = IIf(Not IsNothing(oUser.UserBranches),
                           oUser.UserBranches.Select(Function(z) String.Format("{0} - BranchCode", z.BranchCode)), "")
```

I have also used `oUser.UserBranches.Any`, but still the same exception. Any ideas?

** To the duplicate recommendation, it's actually not since the question combines both the IIF and also an empty array with lambda expressions.

Comment: Use `If()` instead of `IIf()`.

Comment: "Any ideas?" - Yes, select the ""References Tab" after clicking the Project Menu->"Project Name" Properties.  Then under "Imported namespaces", uncheck "Microsoft.VisualBasic".  This will make it harder for you to use the functions (like `IIf`) meant to make VB6 programmers comfortable in VB.Net and instead use `If` or write a standard `If-Then` block.

Comment: What version of VB are you using? If it's VB 14 or later, there is also the question mark operator (see https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Blogs/Tool-Tracker/2015/05/C-Sharp-VB-14-Null-Nothing.aspx). Also, `If()` has a two-parameter version. And there's `$""` (string interpolation). So this might work: `Dim sMatchedBranches = If(oUser.UserBranches?.Select(Function(z) $"{z.BranchCode} - BranchCode"), "")`

Comment: @rskar Nice answer. Please post it as answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @alwaysVBNET - glad that helped! I'll post a very detailed answer for the benefit of future viewers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using VB.NET IIF I get NullReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428959/using-vb-net-iif-i-get-nullreferenceexception)

Comment: @TnTinMn It's not. The focus of the question is performing lamda on an empty list, not the IIF statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would reiterate what @TnTinMn has said: Try to wean off Microsoft.VisualBasic. It's OK to pick-and-choose whatever's useful there - in which case be very thoughtful and intentional (e.g. even C#'ers like InputBox a lot! - [What is the C# version of VB.net's InputDialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97097/what-is-the-c-sharp-version-of-vb-nets-inputdialog)). However, VB today has so many nicer and better ways of getting things done.

The major flaw of ye olde `IIf()` is that it is just some function, which means every parameter gets executed no matter the condition. That makes it barely useful, even in VB6/VBA, because you just can't avoid any run-time-error/exception that you know is going to happen per the condition. `If()` on the other hand is an actual operator, and it delivers exactly what everyone wants - a way to carefully prune what gets executed in an expression without having to write a specialized function.

So the easy answer is just to replace `IIf()` with `If()` and be pretty much done with it:

```
Dim sMatchedBranches = If(Not IsNothing(oUser.UserBranches),
                       oUser.UserBranches.Select(Function(z) String.Format("{0} - BranchCode", z.BranchCode)), "")
```

And one might feel that's good enough. But there's three other tricks in VB to make things nicer yet.

The first is the `?` operator. This is a handy way to say something like `If(oUser.UserBranches Is Nothing, Nothing, oUser.UserBranches.Select(Function(z) String.Format("{0} - BranchCode", z.BranchCode)))`, except with `?` it's now like this:

```
oUser.UserBranches?.Select(Function(z) String.Format("{0} - BranchCode", z.BranchCode))
```

The second trick is string interpolation, in the format of `$"{myVar}"`. Instead of `String.Format("{0} - BranchCode", z.BranchCode)`, it can now be:

```
$"{z.BranchCode} - BranchCode"
```

The third trick is about `If()`: If you give it two parameters, it will give a very handy way of dealing with `Nothing`. `If(x,y)` means if `x` is not `Nothing`, return `x`, otherwise return `y`. (`If(x,y)` means the same as `x ?? y` in C#.)

Putting it all together:

```
Dim sMatchedBranches = If(oUser.UserBranches?.Select(Function(z) $"{z.BranchCode} - BranchCode"), "")
```

Comment: My goal was to get the branch codes as a string. By checking again now the code I get an error. Any ideas?  Dim sMatchedBranches As String = If(oUser.UserBranches?.Select(Function(z) $"{z.BranchCode} - BranchCode"), "")

Comment: Ok, I did this: Dim sMatchedBranches As String = String.Join(",",                                                     oUser.UserBranches?.Select(Function(z) $"{z.BranchCode} - BranchCode")) which works

Comment: So, the goal is a comma-separated list of items? `String.Join` is fine for that, so what you have looks OK to me. But you probably still need to use `If(x,y)` in case oUser.UserBranches is Nothing.

Comment: now that I have put back the if(x,y) instead of CSV I get this: sMatchedBranches = "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[TestBlcWS_winnapp.sr.Branches,System.String]"

Comment: Try this (warning, I'm flying blind here): `Dim sMatchedBranches = String.Join(",", If(oUser.UserBranches?.Select(Function(z) $"{z.BranchCode} - BranchCode"), {""}))` I'm hoping to nudge String.Join towards where its second parameter is something IEnumerable.

Comment: Cool! I hope this is the real answer for you.